# How fix scaling for small screen size in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, resize, screen-size

Target: respect variant screens size.

Problem: Screen's UI does not display well on different devices and producing UI's error

For example: on the iPhone 13 emulator, everything looks as it should, but when you use a smartphone with a screen resolution of 1280x768, everything breaks down

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Auth());
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 255, 247),
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/spikelets.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, left: 49),
                      child: Text(
                        'Добро',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'GoodVibesCyr',
                          fontSize: 92,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      )),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 35),
                      child: Text(
                        'пожаловать!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'TTCommons',
                          fontSize: 54,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 25),
                child: Text(
                  'Мобильный заказ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'TTCommons',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 36,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/backgroundMainButtons.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(41, 0, 0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 6,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 15),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/backgroundMainButtons.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(41, 0, 0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 6,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/backgroundMainButtons.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(41, 0, 0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 6,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 15),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/backgroundMainButtons.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(41, 0, 0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 6,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 15),
                width: 325,
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 152, 71),
                      blurRadius: 0,
                      offset: Offset(0, 10), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 325,
                  height: 60,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'Товары недели',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'TTCommons',
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // <-- Radius
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The provided screen-shots declares more details:

[image: Need To Fix Sizing] [image: Final Required Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many possible solutions:

- Wrap your Column widget by SingleChildScrollView
- Replace Column with Scrollable Widget
- Use "Wrap" Widget instead of "Column" Widget

```html
SafeArea( /// controlls the reset of space
        bottom: false,
        child: Container( /// define the child height witch breaks the SafeArea physics
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/spikelets.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column( /// the child you gonna to update with above possabilities
```

--Update--

As you mentioned in comments about scaling your widgets, there are two ways as I know

first, you can use the [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

secondly, you can create your own sizing service like mine

```html
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class SizeConfig {
  
  /// create singleton instance
  SizeConfig._internal();
  static final SizeConfig _instance = SizeConfig._internal();
  factory SizeConfig() => _instance;


  double screenWidth = Get.context.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? Get.mediaQuery.size.width : Get.mediaQuery.size.height;

  double screenHeight = Get.context.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? Get.mediaQuery.size.height : Get.mediaQuery.size.width;

  double infinityHeight() => double.infinity;

  double infinityWidth() => double.infinity;

  double blockSizeHorizontal() => screenWidth / 100;

  double blockSizeVertical() => screenHeight / 100;

  double _safeAreaHorizontal() => Get.mediaQuery.padding.left + Get.mediaQuery.padding.right;

  double _safeAreaVertical() => Get.mediaQuery.padding.top + Get.mediaQuery.padding.bottom;

  double safeBlockHorizontal() => (screenWidth - (Get.context.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? _safeAreaHorizontal() : _safeAreaVertical())) / 100;

  double safeBlockVertical() => (screenHeight - (Get.context.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? _safeAreaVertical() : _safeAreaHorizontal())) / 100;

  double fontSize50() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.0;
  double fontSize51() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.1;
  double fontSize52() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.2;
  double fontSize53() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.3;
  double fontSize54() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.4;
  double fontSize55() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.5;
  double fontSize56() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.6;
  double fontSize57() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.7;
  double fontSize58() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.8;
  double fontSize59() => safeBlockHorizontal() * 5.9;
}
```

I use this SizeConfig() service with [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), and using it as

> width: SizeConfig().safeBlockHorizontal() * 10, // 10% from screen width

> height: SizeConfig().safeBlockVertical() * 10 // 10% from screen height

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just started learning flutter. is it possible to scale my code so that all the elements are positioned the same as in the iphone version? scale depending on the size of the screen or something else.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WVrVnJN
https://text-host.ru/bez-zagolovka-1092

Comment: Please review the updated answer, And do not hesitate to ask if any are not clear :)

Comment: Thanks so much!