# Flutter screens sizes

Tags: android, flutter, dart, screen-size

```
Container(height:50, width:50)
```

How come I define a container of 50px * 50px (with some text inside), but the container is quite smaller on **SAMSUNG SCREEN** than on **HUAWEI SCREEN**. There even is an overflow.

I would understand if this happened while using media query.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732192/flutter-same-size-value-widget-has-different-actual-size-on-android-and-ios)

Can someone explain, please?

Comment: could you include what you have done with Media Querry?

Comment: may you screen overflow is because of other widget, could you include a sample code that regenerate that issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881154/how-fix-scaling-for-small-screen-size-in-flutter Different devices have different resolutions and dpi, which causes your widgets to look smaller/bigger on different devices. The answer also refers to that problem (scaling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different devices have different resolutions and dpi, which causes your widgets to look smaller/bigger on different devices

in  `Container(height:50, width:50)` 50 is not **pixel** unit, it is **dp**

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

For example, with a device with a dpi of **320**, with **10 dp** we have: `10 * (320/160) = 20 px`, 1 dp is equivalent to 2 px.

if you want convert pixel to device size unit, try:

```
 double convertFromPixel(double pixel){
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio; //3.5
    var value = pixel / size; //3.5dp = 1px
    return value; 
  }
```

and use:

```
Container(
    height: convertFromPixel(50), //50 pixel, height will auto size 
    width: convertFromPixel(50),
)
```

Comment: So since dp &/or dpi may differ from one device to another, there is no way to be totaly sure to have a block of 5cm*5cm on every screen sizes, right?

Comment: I just updated my answer